# Aligning layout Elements

Tags: android, layout

Hello I would like to align the following android elements like this:

**Align:**

```
textView_NomeCantiereDefault  --space--   textView_NomeCantiere
textView_ClienteINFO         --space--- textView_Cliente
```

To perform this type of alignment I'm using a linearlayout in fact that the default linearlayout has 3 child columns, I would like to make use of just one can make it get the alignment described above?

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

        <!-- TextView NomeCantiere-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_NomeCantiereDefault"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Nome Cantiere:"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="35dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        <!-- TextView che contiene il nome del cantiere-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_NomeCantiere"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text=".."
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="300dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        <!-- TextView Cliente-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_ClienteINFO"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text="Ragione Sociale:"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!-- TextView che contiene il nome del Cliente-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Cliente"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text=".."
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"> <!-- CHANGE THIS TO VERTICAL-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- TextView NomeCantiere-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_NomeCantiereDefault"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Nome Cantiere:"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="35dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <!-- TextView che contiene il nome del cantiere-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_NomeCantiere"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text=".."
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="300dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- TextView Cliente-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_ClienteINFO"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text="Ragione Sociale:"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <!-- TextView che contiene il nome del Cliente-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Cliente"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text=".."
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With your solution everything was correct, textView_Client in which the characters were aligned one below the other to solve this I changed the width of textView_Client in 200dp is now perfect, thanks for the help

Comment: @riki I did the same with relative layout and got down vote from you.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- TextView NomeCantiere-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_NomeCantiereDefault"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Nome Cantiere:"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <!-- TextView che contiene il nome del cantiere-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_NomeCantiere"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text=".."
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp">

        <!-- TextView Cliente-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_ClienteINFO"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Ragione Sociale:"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <!-- TextView che contiene il nome del Cliente-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Cliente"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text=".."
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```